# Assigning fetch to a variable which is in json format typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using the below code in typescript & node.js to get data from a URL data is fetched as a Jason format. However I am unable to assign this to variable x. I am confused as to how this code works seeing as the function is proceeded with fetch. I'm also unable to figure out how to take what looks like a variable data=myJson from the return of the function and then make x equal to it. Ultimately I'm looking for X to be equal to the returned Jason data.

I have attempted making x equal to fetch and its function but this does not yield any return.

```
let data  = ''

fetch('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BITFINEX/BTCUSD/data.json to 
').then(function(response) {
   return response.json();}).then(function(myJson) {data=myJson 
console.log(data)
 });


let x = // I am trying to make this variable equal the returned json file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function x is returning a promise. the fetched data will be presented sometime in the future by that time the exucution of `let x = something` is already passed so, when the promise succeeds it calls the callback passed in the then function. so perform the next operations that are to be performed with fetched data in the then accepting method callback

```js
let data  = ''
let x;
fetch('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BITFINEX/BTCUSD/data.json to 
').then(function(response) {
   return response.json();}).then(function(myJson) {data=myJson 
console.log(data)
   x = myJson;
   // do what you want to do with x here
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, so everything stays local to that function. This is helpful as I can just as you say put what I need inside this function. Just on a side note is their away to get to myJson from outside the function?

Comment: I’m not really sure but I think there is a way by saying await to the promise that will wait for the promise to return a result or an error. But that’s a bad practice. So I don’t recommend you to do that.